# Lazy Processing of Streams

Tags: java, c++, design-patterns, programming-practices, haskell

I have the following problem scenario:

- I have a text file and I have to read it and split it into lines.
- Some lines might need to be dropped (according to criteria that are not fixed).
- The lines that are not dropped must be parsed into some predefined records.
- Records that are not valid must be dropped.
- Duplicate records may exist and, in such a case, they are consecutive. If duplicate / multiple records exist, only one item should be kept.
- The remaining records should be grouped according to the value contained in one field; all records belonging to the same group appear one after another (e.g. AAAABBBBCCDEEEFF and so on).
- The records of each group should be numbered (1, 2, 3, 4, ...). For each group the numbering starts from 1.
- The records must then be saved somewhere / consumed in the same order as they were produced.

I have to implement this in Java or C++.

My first idea was to define functions / methods like:

- One method to get all the lines from the file.
- One method to filter out the unwanted lines.
- One method to parse the filtered lines into valid records.
- One method to remove duplicate records.
- One method to group records and number them.

The problem is that the data I am going to read can be too big and might not fit into main memory: so I cannot just construct all these lists and apply my functions one after the other.

On the other hand, I think I do not need to fit all the data in main memory at once because once a record has been consumed all its underlying data (basically the lines of text between the previous record and the current record, and the record itself) can be disposed of.

With the little knowledge I have of Haskell I have immediately thought about some kind of lazy evaluation, in which instead of applying functions to lists that have been completely computed, I have different streams of data that are built on top of each other and, at each moment, only the needed portion of each stream is materialized in main memory.

But I have to implement this in Java or C++. So my question is which design pattern or other technique can allow me to implement this lazy processing of streams in one of these languages.

Comment: If homework, please tag as such.

Comment: Do you have a database?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen We've [blacklisted \[homework\]](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3202/blacklist-homework), here's [why](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/removing-the-homework-tag)...

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: It is not homework, it is a project I am working on. This pattern is occurring again and again and I am trying to find a more general solution / approach.

Comment: @Emmad Kareem: I do not have a database and even if I had I would like to see the data as streams and process the data by composing functions on streams. I find it is a very elegant and efficient approach, but I am still learning how it works.

Comment: When you have large data volume, eliminating duplicates, grouping and sorting should be performed using the services of a relational database.

Comment: @YannisRizos I disagree with the removal of the homework tag.  Homework needs a completely different kind of answer than non-homework. But, duly noted.

Comment: @EmmadKareem you always load your log files into a database for processing or you just use `grep`?

Comment: Of course you use grep for a quick and straightforward processing but what this questions is asking for is not what you use grep for. For example, you can't use grep to group data. You could build an entire program on one line of unix, but how many people can fix it?

Comment: @Emmad Kareem: My issue with a database solution is that while it might solve the particular problem I have described above, it does not solve the general problem of combining a sequence of filters f1, ..., fn on data streams where the output of filter f1, ..., fn-1 is the input of filter f2, ..., fn, and have the filters process data in a lazy way. I think the iterator solution proposed by Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen is a good approach.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Well, the Meta discussion asking for it's removal is highly upvoted (for Meta), so I don't think there's much we can do now. If you feel strongly about it, you can still add an answer to the Meta question explaining why you feel the tag is useful, and with enough support from the community we can always bring it back.

Comment: @Emmad Kareem: I can add the explanation to the main question if you think it is important to have it there.

Comment: No need at all, as long as you got your issue resolved we are all happy. The accepted solution is also very smart :)

Comment: Yes, maybe the iterator solution is all that there is to it. No need to look for a more complicated solution when there is a simple one.

Comment: @YannisRizos not worth the effort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should look into iterators if deciding for Java.

Write an `Iterator<String>` that reads a line from the file.  Write a filtering iterator that accepts the above iterator in the constructor and only generate those lines you are interested in.  Write a splitting `Iterator<Record>` that accepts a string iterator in the constructor, and splits each line into a record.  And so on.

You will most likely find that you will do the processing in the "are there more?" section to get the logic right.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea: I had been thinking about more complex solutions but probably iterators (possibly with small adaptations) are what I need. Thanks for the answer! +1.

Comment: When you have experiences to share, please do.

Comment: I have the following solution (sketch): special generic iterator interface with methods hasNext(), next() [get and consume], peekNext() [get, do not consume], and a generic class IteratorCombinator that produces a new iterator from a source iterator. The above-mentioned methods are all generic and based on a protected method produceNext() that each custom combinator must implement. As a front-end to the outermost iterator I have a class that produces a list from the first n elements. In this way, I removed most of the boilerplate.

Comment: In my experience you do not need even that.  Just implement the interface and do the hard work in hasNext().

Answer (score 2):

Even though this question has an accepted answer already, I have recently found another interesting solution, which I would like to share here.
I would be interested to learn about other techniques for implementing streams in Java.

The first ideas for my solution came from a course on Scala in which I was able to experiment with Scala's library streams (`scala.collection.immutable.Stream`). The course explained that a stream in Scala is very similar to a list (sequence of cons cells) in which the tail() function / method is computed lazily: the tail sequence is computed on demand when tail() is called for the first time, and cached for further accesses.

Of course, the tail is computed lazily as well, i.e. only the first cons cell of the tail is generated when tail() is called: subsequent elements of the tail stream are generated when tail() is called on this stream, and so on.

The second part of the solution came from [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159804/how-do-you-encode-algebraic-data-types-in-a-c-or-java-like-language) and some of its answers: the only extension I needed was to implement cons cells with lazy tails.

Based on this solution, it was easy to define the usual functions (methods) `take` and `drop`, and the higher-order functions `map`, `filter`, `dropWhile`, `takeWhile` which also work lazily on streams. With these tools the original problem of manipulating streams of strings is much easier to solve.

**My Solution**

I first implemented lists as indicated in the `programmers` question and then implemented a similar data type `Stream<T>`.
A cons cell consists of an object of class `Cons<T>` containing

1. A value of type `T` (the head), and
2. A closure (function object) with one `apply` method returning the tail stream.

Here are the key definitions:

```
// An interface to store functions (closures) that are
// used to produce a stream's tail on demand.
public interface IStreamFunction<A>
{
  public Stream<A> apply();
}

// Wrapper object that invokes a stream function
// and then stores the result for future invocations of tail().
public class Memoizer<Stream<A>>
{
  private final IStreamFunction<A> _f;

  private Stream<A> _v;

  public Memoizer(IStreamFunction<A> f)
  {
    _f = f;

    _v = null;
  }

  public Stream<A> value()
  {
    if (_v == null)
    {
      _v = _f.apply();
    }

    return _v;
  }
}

// Stream class with two subclasses implementing the empty stream
// and a cons cell, respectively.
public abstract class Stream<A>
{
  // Private constructor cannot be called by any subclasses except inner classes.
  private Stream()
  {
  }

  public abstract A head();

  public abstract Stream<A> tail();

  public abstract boolean isEmpty();

  // Empty stream.
  public static final class Nil<A> extends Stream<A>
  {
    public Nil()
    {
    }

    public A head()
    {
      throw new NoSuchElementException("Nil.head");
    }

    public Stream<A> tail()
    {
      throw new NoSuchElementException("Nil.tail");
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
      return true;
    }
  }

  // Cons cell.
  public static final class Cons<A> extends Stream<A>
  {
    private final A _h;
    private final Memoizer<Stream<A>> _m;

    public Cons(A h, IStreamFunction<A> f)
    {
      _h = h;
      _m = new Memoizer<Stream<A>>(f);
    }

    public A head()
    {
      return _h;
    }

    public Stream<A> tail()
    {
      return _m.value();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```