# How do you encode Algebraic Data Types in a C#- or Java-like language?

Tags: java, c#, scala, haskell, algebraic-data-type

There are some problems which are easily solved by Algebraic Data Types, for example a List type can be very succinctly expressed as:

```
data ConsList a = Empty | ConsCell a (ConsList a)

consmap f Empty          = Empty
consmap f (ConsCell a b) = ConsCell (f a) (consmap f b)

l = ConsCell 1 (ConsCell 2 (ConsCell 3 Empty))
consmap (+1) l
```

This particular example is in Haskell, but it would be similar in other languages with native support for Algebraic Data Types.

It turns out that there is an obvious mapping to OO-style subtyping: the datatype becomes an abstract base class and every data constructor becomes a concrete subclass. Here's an example in Scala:

```
sealed abstract class ConsList[+T] {
  def map[U](f: T => U): ConsList[U]
}

object Empty extends ConsList[Nothing] {
  override def map[U](f: Nothing => U) = this
}

final class ConsCell[T](first: T, rest: ConsList[T]) extends ConsList[T] {
  override def map[U](f: T => U) = new ConsCell(f(first), rest.map(f))
}

val l = new ConsCell(1, new ConsCell(2, new ConsCell(3, Empty)))
l.map(1+)
```

The only thing needed beyond naive subclassing is a way to *seal* classes, i.e. a way to make it impossible to add subclasses to a hierarchy.

How would you approach this problem in a language like C# or Java? The two stumbling blocks I found when trying to use Algebraic Data Types in C# were:

- I couldn't figure out what the bottom type is called in C# (i.e. I couldn't figure out what to put into `class Empty : ConsList< ??? >`)
- I couldn't figure out a way to *seal* `ConsList` so that no subclasses can be added to the hierarchy

What would be the most idiomatic way to implement Algebraic Data Types in C# and/or Java? Or, if it isn't possible, what would be the idiomatic replacement?

Comment: I don't really know C#, but wouldn't you have to parametrize `Empty` on the list's type? That is, in Haskell `[] :: [a]`, so I expect something like `Empty<A>`, the same as `ConsList<A>`. Then you could do something like `class Empty<A> : ConsList<A>`, assuming the syntax actually works that way :P.

Comment: Of interest: [Encoding algebraic data types in C#](http://bugsquash.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/encoding-algebraic-data-types-in-c.html)

Comment: @AakashM: That would actually be a good answer, can't believe I didn't find it.

Comment: C# is OOP language. Solve problems using OOP. Don't try using any other paradigm.

Comment: @Euphoric C# has become a quite usable functional language with C# 3.0. First-class functions, built-in common functional operations, monads.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis: C# has subtyping, so it makes more sense to make `Empty` a subtype of `ConsList<T>` for all `T`. Since `ConsList` is covariant in `T`, you can make `Empty` a subtype of `ConsList<T>` by making it a subtype of `ConsList<Bottom>`, where `Bottom` is the bottom type, i.e. the subtype of all types. In Scala, `Bottom` is spelled `Nothing`, but apparently C# doesn't have a bottom type. (Or rather: it probably does have a bottom type, but it doesn't allow you to write it down.)

Comment: @Euphoric: So is Scala. In fact, Scala is probably more purely OO than C#, for example, C# has separate language constructs for first class functions (delegates), whereas in Scala first class functions are just a design pattern (any object which has an `apply` method is a function), albeit a design pattern with library support and syntactic sugar. You might also notice that the Scala example I gave is not very idiomatic code, precisely because I tried to use *only* the pure OO subset of Scala. I used only polymorphism, inheritance and encapsulation.

Comment: @Euphoric: some domains are easy to model with objects and hard to model with algebraic data types, some are the opposite. Knowing how to do both gives you more flexibility in modeling your domain. And like I said, mapping algebraic data types to typical OO concepts is not that complex: the data type becomes an abstract base class (or an interface, or an abstract trait), the data constructors become concrete implementation subclasses. That gives you an open algebraic data type. Restrictions on inheritance give you a closed algebraic data type. Polymorphism gives you case discrimination.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis: Another way to look at it: in Haskell, the empty list is a polymorphic value, as you point out. AFAIK, neither C# nor Java allow polymorphic values, so you simply can't have an empty list of type `Empty<T>`, it has to be of some concrete type `Empty<Something>`. Since you want that type to be substitutable for *every* empty list, it needs to be a subtype of all lists, which can be achieved if `Something` is a subtype of all types, i.e. a bottom type.

Comment: Java sort-of has polymorphic values in some cases because its generics are implemented by erasure. You could have a single instance of `Empty` which is cast by an accessor method to `Empty<T>`. You'll get a couple of warnings unless you suppress them, but I believe this is actually used in the standard library for things like `Collections.emptySet()`.

Comment: @Euphoric, paradigm, schmaradigm, who cares? ADTs are orthogonal to the functional programming (or OOP or whatever else). Encoding an AST of any language is quite a pain without decent ADTs support, and compiling that language is a pain without another paradigm-agnostic feature, pattern matching.

Comment: Very interesting question. I tried to code lists in Java following the suggestions of James and Petr. Now I wanted to try and implement streams (lists in which the tail is evaluated lazily, similar to streams in Scala). Is there a way to do this in Java? Does it make sense to post this as a separate question?

Comment: @Giorgio: Java doesn't support lazy evaluation natively, therefore you need to "fake" it. The common way to fake lazy evaluation is with lambdas. Of course, Java doesn't have those, either, so you need to "fake" those as well, using anonymous inner classes implementing Single-Abstract-Method Interfaces.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag: Thanks for the hints. As far as I understand, anonymous inner classes in Java are a generalization of lambdas, using a different (more verbose syntax). I will try it out, maybe it can be encapsulated enough to be usable.

Comment: >"Solve problems using OOP. Don't try using any other paradigm."
What if I hate OOP? http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/24887/6485

Comment: C# isn't real OOP...  Real OOP(Talking about Smalltalk/Alan Kay) has stuff like __getattr__, method_missing, metaobject protocols, JavaScript's prototypes, interactive development, and uses clojures/blocks instead of ravioli objects...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of the other answers here are ***outdated*** (as of me writing this answer).

Java has first class support for Abstract Data Types (ADT's) now. The easiest way to create an ADT is by using [`Records`](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395) and [`Sealed Types`](https://openjdk.org/jeps/409). Both of these are features that released in Java 16 and 17, respectively.

Here is an example that uses them, plus a little bit of pattern-matching, switch expressions, var, and lambdas, to be able to emulate the original example shown in the question.

```java
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;

public class abc
{

   sealed interface ConsList<A> permits Empty, ConsCell {}
   record Empty<A>() implements ConsList<A> {}
   record ConsCell<A>(A head, ConsList<A> tail) implements ConsList<A> {}

   public static <A> ConsList<A> applyFunctionToConsList(final UnaryOperator<A> function, final ConsList<A> list)
   {

      return
         switch (list)
         {

            case Empty<A> e                      -> e;
            case ConsCell<A>(var head, var tail) -> new ConsCell<>(function.apply(head), applyFunctionToConsList(function, tail));

         };

   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      var list = new ConsCell<>(1, new ConsCell<>(2, new ConsCell<>(3, new Empty<>())));
      System.out.println(applyFunctionToConsList(i -> i + 1, list));

   }

}
```

If I run the above code, I get the following output.

```
ConsCell[head=2, tail=ConsCell[head=3, tail=ConsCell[head=4, tail=Empty[]]]]
```

Here is another example.

```java
var list = new ConsCell<>(1, new ConsCell<>(2, new ConsCell<>(3, new Empty<>())));
System.out.println(applyFunctionToConsList(i -> i * 3, list));

//ConsCell[head=3, tail=ConsCell[head=6, tail=ConsCell[head=9, tail=Empty[]]]]
```

Comment: And if anyone is confused on how to run this, you can run this on the current latest version (today, that is Java 20), and using the following command --- `java --enable-preview --source 20 abc.java`

Comment: And now that Java 21 has released, you no longer need to add `--enable-preview`. It has exited preview and is now a permanent part of the language. If you are using Java 21 or later, just compile the above code, and it should work with no problem.

Answer (score 52):

There is an easy, but boilerplate heavy way to seal classes in Java.  You put a private constructor in the base class then make subclasses inner classes of it.

```
public abstract class List<A> {

   // private constructor is uncallable by any sublclasses except inner classes
   private List() {
   }

   public static final class Nil<A> extends List<A> {
   }

   public static final class Cons<A> extends List<A> {
      public final A head;
      public final List<A> tail;

      public Cons(A head, List<A> tail) {
         this.head = head;
         this.tail = tail;
      }
   }
}
```

Tack on a visitor pattern for dispatch.

My project [jADT: Java Algebraic DataTypes](https://github.com/JamesIry/jADT) generates all that boilerplate for you.

Comment: Somehow I'm not surprised to see your name pop up here! Thanks, I didn't know this idiom.

Comment: When you said "boilerplate heavy" I was prepared for something much worse ;-) Java can be pretty bad with boilerplate, sometimes.

Comment: but this does not compose : you have no way to specialize type A without having to assert it through a cast (I think)

Comment: This unfortunately seems unable to represent some more complex sum types, eg `Either`. See [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48143268/java-tagged-union-sum-types)

Answer (score 25):

You can achieve this by using the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), which will supplement pattern matching. For example

```
data List a = Nil | Cons { value :: a, sublist :: List a }
```

can be written in Java as

```java
interface List<T> {
    public <R> R accept(Visitor<T,R> visitor);

    public static interface Visitor<T,R> {
        public R visitNil();
        public R visitCons(T value, List<T> sublist);
    }
}

final class Nil<T> implements List<T> {
    public Nil() { }

    public <R> R accept(Visitor<T,R> visitor) {
        return visitor.visitNil();
    }
}
final class Cons<T> implements List<T> {
    public final T value;
    public final List<T> sublist;

    public Cons(T value, List<T> sublist) {
        this.value = value;
        this.sublist = sublist;
    }

    public <R> R accept(Visitor<T,R> visitor) {
        return visitor.visitCons(value, sublist);
    }
}
```

Sealing is achieved by the `Visitor` class. Each of its methods declares how to deconstruct one of the subclasses. You could add more subclasses, but it would have to implement `accept` and by calling one of the `visit...` methods, so it would either have to behave like `Cons` or like `Nil`.

Comment: I have explored this encoding in my blog: https://garciat.com/2020/05/07/java-adt/

Answer (score 17):

If you abuse C# named parameters (introduced in C# 4.0), you can make algebraic data types that are easy to match on:

```
Either<string, string> e = MonthName(2);

// Match with no return value.
e.Match
(
    Left: err => { Console.WriteLine("Could not convert month: {0}", err); },
    Right: name => { Console.WriteLine("The month is {0}", name); }
);

// Match with a return value.
string monthName =
    e.Match
    (
        Left: err => null,
        Right: name => name
    );
Console.WriteLine("monthName: {0}", monthName);
```

Here is the implementation of the `Either` class:

```
public abstract class Either<L, R>
{
    // Subclass implementation calls the appropriate continuation.
    public abstract T Match<T>(Func<L, T> Left, Func<R, T> Right);

    // Convenience wrapper for when the caller doesn't want to return a value
    // from the match expression.
    public void Match(Action<L> Left, Action<R> Right)
    {
        this.Match<int>(
            Left: x => { Left(x); return 0; },
            Right: x => { Right(x); return 0; }
        );
    }
}

public class Left<L, R> : Either<L, R>
{
    L Value {get; set;}

    public Left(L Value)
    {
        this.Value = Value;
    }

    public override T Match<T>(Func<L, T> Left, Func<R, T> Right)
    {
        return Left(Value);
    }
}

public class Right<L, R> : Either<L, R>
{
    R Value { get; set; }

    public Right(R Value)
    {
        this.Value = Value;
    }

    public override T Match<T>(Func<L, T> Left, Func<R, T> Right)
    {
        return Right(Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've seen a Java version of this technique before, but lambdas and named parameters make it so much readable. +1!

Comment: I think the problem here is that Right isn't generic over the type of error. Something like: `class Right<R> : Either<Bot,R>`,
where Either is changed to an interface with covariant (out) type parameters, and Bot is the bottom type (subtype of every other type, opposite of Object). I don't think C# has a bottom type.

Answer (score 5):

In C#, you can't have that `Empty` type, because, due to reification, the base types are different for different member types. You can only have `Empty<T>`; not that useful.

In Java, you can have `Empty : ConsList` due to type erasure, but I am not sure whether the type checker wouldn't scream somewhere.

However since both languages have `null`, you can think of *all* their reference types as being "Whatever|Null". So you'd just use the `null` as the "Empty" to avoid having to specify what it derives.

Comment: The problem with `null` is that it is too general: it represents the absence of *anything*, i.e. *emptiness* in general, but I want to represent the absence of list elements, i.e. an empty list in particular. An empty list and an empty tree should have distinct types. Also, the empty list needs to be an actual value because it still has behavior of its own, so it needs to have its own methods. To construct the list `[1, 2, 3]`, I want to say `Empty.prepend(3).prepend(2).prepend(1)` (or in a language with right-associative operators `1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Empty`), but I can't say `null.prepend …`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: The nulls do have distinct types. You can also easily create typed constant with value null for the purpose. But it's true you can't call methods on it. Your approach with methods does not work without element-type-specific Empty anyway.

Comment: some crafty extension methods can fake 'method' calls on nulls (of course its all really static)

Comment: You can have an `Empty` and an `Empty<>` and abuse implicit conversion operators to allow a fairly practical simulation, if you want.  Essentially, you use `Empty` in code, but all type signatures etc only use the generic variants.

Answer (score 4):

The data type `ConsList<A>` can be represented as an interface. The interface exposes a single `deconstruct` method which allows you to "deconstruct" a value of that type - that is, to handle each of the possible constructors. Calls to a `deconstruct` method are analogous to a `case of` form in Haskell or ML.

```
interface ConsList<A> {
  <R> R deconstruct(
    Function<Unit, R> emptyCase,
    Function<Pair<A,ConsList<A>>, R> consCase
  );
}
```

The `deconstruct` method takes a "callback" function for each constructor in the ADT. In our case, it takes a function for the empty list case, and another function for the "cons cell" case.

Each callback function accepts as arguments the values which are accepted by the constructor. So the "empty list" case takes no arguments, but the "cons cell" case takes two arguments: the head and the tail of the list.

We can encode these "multiple arguments" using `Tuple` classes, or using currying. In this example, I chose to use a simple `Pair` class.

The interface is implemented once for each constructor. First, we have the implementation for the "empty list". The `deconstruct` implementation simply calls the `emptyCase` callback function.

```
class ConsListEmpty<A> implements ConsList<A> {
  public ConsListEmpty() {}

  public <R> R deconstruct(
    Function<Unit, R> emptyCase,
    Function<Pair<A,ConsList<A>>, R> consCase
  ) {
    return emptyCase.apply(new Unit());
  }
}
```

Then we implement the "cons cell" case similarly. This time the class has properties: the head and tail of the non-empty list. In the `deconstruct` implementation, those properties are passed to the `consCase` callback function.

```
class ConsListConsCell<A> implements ConsList<A> {
  private A head;
  private ConsList<A> tail;

  public ConsListCons(A head, ConsList<A> tail) {
    this.head = head;
    this.tail = tail;
  }

  public <R> R deconstruct(
    Function<Unit, R> emptyCase,
    Function<Pair<A,ConsList<A>>, R> consCase
  ) {
    return consCase.apply(new Pair<A,ConsList<A>>(this.head, this.tail));
  }
}
```

Here is an example of using this encoding of ADTs: we can write a `reduce` function which is the usual fold over lists.

```
<T> T reduce(Function<Pair<T,A>,T> reducer, T initial, ConsList<T> l) {
  return l.deconstruct(
    ((unit) -> initial),
    ((t) -> reduce(reducer, reducer.apply(initial, t.v1), t.v2))
  );
}
```

This is analogous to this implementation in Haskell:

```
reduce reducer initial l = case l of
  Empty -> initial
  Cons t_v1 t_v2  -> reduce reducer (reducer initial t_v1) t_v2
```

Comment: Interesting approach, very nice! I can see the connection to F# Active Patterns and Scala Extractors (and there's probably a link there to Haskell Views as well, which I know nothing about, unfortunately). I hadn't thought of moving the responsibility for pattern matching over the data constructors into the ADT instance itself.

Answer (score 3):

> The only thing needed beyond naive subclassing is a way to seal classes, i.e. a way to make it impossible to add subclasses to a hierarchy.

In Java you can't.  But you can declare the base class as package private, which means that all direct subclasses have to belong to the same package as the base class.  If you then declare the subclasses as final, they can't be subclassed any further.

I don't know if this would address your real problem though ...

Comment: I don't have a real problem, or I would have posted this on StackOverflow, not here :-) An important property of Algebraic Data Types is that they can be *closed*, which means that the number of cases is fixed: in this example, a list is either empty or it isn't. If I can statically ensure that this is the case, then I can make dynamic casts or dynamic `intanceof` checks "pseudo-type-safe" (i.e.: I know it's safe, even if the compiler doesn't), by simply ensuring that I always check those two cases. If, however, someone else adds a new subclass, then I can get runtime errors I didn't expect.

Comment: @JörgWMittag - Well Java clearly doesn't support that ... in the strong sense that you seem to be wanting.  Of course, you can do various things to block unwanted subtyping at runtime, but then you get "runtime errors that you don't expect".

Answer (score 2):

> The only thing needed beyond naive subclassing is a way to seal classes, i.e. a way to make it impossible to add subclasses to a hierarchy.
>
> How would you approach this problem in a language like C# or Java?

There isn't a good way to do this, but if you're willing to live with a hideous hack then you can add some explicit type checking to the abstract base class' constructor. In Java, this would be something like

```
protected ConsList() {
    Class<?> clazz = getClass();
    if (clazz != Empty.class && clazz != ConsCell.class) throw new Exception();
}
```

In C# it's more complicated because of the reified generics - the simplest approach might be to convert the type to a string and mangle that.

Note that in Java even this mechanism can theoretically be bypassed by someone who really wants to via the serialisation model or `sun.misc.Unsafe`.

Comment: It wouldn't be more complicated in C#: `Type type = this.GetType(); if (type != typeof(Empty<T>) && type != typeof(ConsCell<T>)) throw new Exception();`

Comment: @svick, well observed. I wasn't taking into account that the base type would be parameterised.

Comment: Brilliant! I guess this is good enough for doing "manual static type checking". I'm more looking to eliminate honest programming errors rather than malicious intent.