# suggest structure for classes that maps to json with dynamic data without using dynamic or object reference

Tags: c#, json

this is a kind of data i have to de-serialize

```
{
    "id": "M:11427",
    "title": "DAX30",
    "nextStartId": "S:727831",
    "sections": [
        {
            "type": "HIGHLIGHTS",
            "baseResults": [ values of type highlights ],
            "hasMore": true
        },
        {
            "type": "CHART",
            "hasMore": false,
            "chartTypes": [ string values ]
        },
        {
            "type": "TWEETS",
            "baseResults": [ values of type tweets ],
            "hasMore": true
        }]
}
```

I have to serialize & deserialize them all. I want to create something that can hold the values corresponding to baseResults.

there is a main class that represent the whole json

```
class Data 
{
...
ObservableCollection<Section> sections{get;set;}
...
}
```

then there is a class that represents the data in **sections** array of main json

```
class Section
{
string type{get;set;}// thi elements decides what kind of data would be in baseResults
dynamic baseResults{get;set;} //it should hold ObservableCollection of either Highlights or Tweets etc.
}
```

base class for type of data coming in **baseResults** array is an abstract class `class CategoryData`
and its children are `class Highlights` & `class Tweets`

I am using `dynamic` since I can not assign an `ObservableCollection<CategoryData>` with `ObservableCollection<Highlights>`. But I don't want to use this dynamic or object type instead I want something relevant. please suggest me what could be a better approach for this problem.

Comment: Do you do the serialization&deserialization manually, or do you use some library?

Comment: @Euphoric basically I am using newtonsoft-json library. but for this particular json, i had to do manual de/serialization.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're trying to find a statically-typed way to say "a value of type `Section` can be either a value of type `Highlights`, `Chart`, or `Tweets`". There are many terms for this, including [tagged union, discriminated union, variant, or sum type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) but they all refer to the same concept. Sum types are a standard feature in statically-typed functional programming languages, but with a bit of ingenuity [you can roll your own in C#](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/228125/116461). Using that answer as a template, and adding `sealed` to make sure no one adds any extra subclasses, your `Section` type would look something like this:

```
public abstract class Section
{
    // Prevent subclassing outside of this scope
    private Section() {}

    // Subclass implementation calls the appropriate function.
    public abstract R Match<R>(Func<H, R> IfHighlight, Func<C, R> IfChart, Func<T, R> IfTweet);

    // Convenience wrapper for when the caller doesn't want to return a value
    // from the match expression.
    public sealed void Match(Action<H> IfHighlight, Action<C> IfChart, Action<T> IfTweet)
    {
        this.Match<int>(
            IfHighlight: Section => { IfHighlight(Section); return 0; },
            IfChart: Section => { IfChart(Section); return 0; },
            IfTweet: Section => { IfTweet(Section); return 0; }
        );
    }

    // From here on down, you define your specific types as usual, and override Match to call
    // the correct function

    public sealed class Highlight : Section
    {
        // Implementation goes here

        public override R Match<R>(Func<H, R> IfHighlight, Func<C, R> IfChart, Func<T, R> IfTweet)
        {
            return IfHighlight(this);
        }
    }

    public class Chart : Section
    {
        // Implementation goes here

        public override R Match<R>(Func<H, R> IfHighlight, Func<C, R> IfChart, Func<T, R> IfTweet)
        {
            return IfChart(this);
        }
    }

    public class Tweet : Section
    {
        // Implementation goes here

        public override R Match<R>(Func<H, R> IfHighlight, Func<C, R> IfChart, Func<T, R> IfTweet)
        {
            return IfTweet(this);
        }
    }
}
```

With that in place, you can declare variables of type `Section`, and act on them by passing 3 functions to the `Match` methods:

```
Section section = deserializeJson()
section.Match(
    IfHighlight: highlight => /* code to use if you get a Highlight */
    IfChart: chart => /* ... */
    IfTweet: tweet => /* ... */
);
```

You could just as easily have a collection of `Section`s and operate on them that way when you iterate over it.

Answer (score 0):

How about using generics:

```
class Section<TCategoryData> where TCategoryData : CategoryData
{
    string type{get;set;}
    ObservableCollection<TCategoryData> baseResults{get;set;}
}


class HighlightSection : Section<Highlights> {}

class TweetSection : Section<Tweets> {}
```

Comment: this would not work, as I have to decide which class to instantiate based on type which is a member of Section itself.

Comment: So how do you expect it to be statically typed?

Comment: I was looking for something equivalent of wildcard of java however I don't think its possible, but is there no better way to handle it or would u suggest having ObservableCollection<object> is the only better possible way?

Comment: You mean `ObservableObject<CategoryData>`? Yes, and I believe it will be as good as wildcards is this (_read only_) use case

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to choose concrete subtype of `Section` BEFORE you create the instance. The `type` property should not even be in a `Section` and should be tied to what subclass the instance is.

But how to do this depends on how you are doing the serialization and deserialization.