# Entities optional relations: separate classes or single class?

Tags: java, architecture

Lets focus on a domain object that is related to **more** other (different!) entities. Sometimes we need one relation and sometimes the other. Let's be agile and say: we don't know in a front how many other relations there will be.

In other words: we have object **A** that is related one-to-one to **B** and one-to-many to **C** and again one-to-one to **D** and so on. Now, when developing the presentation tier, it often needs a lot of data to display; like table of **A** with **B**, or on other place one **A** with many **C** and so on.

How we gonna model these relationships?

Here is an example: `Competition`. Sometimes it comes and needs to be used with e.g. `Venue`. Sometimes with e.g. `List<Event>`. Since you care about performances, let's also say that the related objects (`Venue` and list of `Event`s) come from the single input/repository method/finder method/one SQL join  (however you call it) - and that they can be *injected* into `Competition` using some mapping tool. This way we express the actual relationship between the entities.

Question: should we keep both relations/references in the `Competition` class and ignore the other when one is used, or we should make many separate classes - one for each relation? (It doesn't matter if it is 1-1 relation or 1-many, the question is the same.)

In other words, should we have:

**[A]**

Everything in the single class. Getter methods do represents relationships. It's on us to fill the object if relation is needed.

```
class Competition {
    ... competition data...

    private Venue venue;
    public Venue getVenue() {
        return venue;
    }

    private List<Event> events;
    public List<Event> getEvents() {
        return events;
    }
}
```

But then, when your application method return a `Competition` you don't know what relations are populated and you have to figure that out by looking the application methods code or by method name (e.g. `findCompetitionWithEvents...()`).

**[B]**

For each relationship we have a type or interface. One way to do so, without interfaces for the simplicity of this example, is:

```
class CompetitionVenue extends Competition {
    private Venue venue;
    public Venue getVenue() {
        return venue;
    }
}
```

and

```
class CompetitionEvents extends Competition {
    private List<Event> events;
    public List<Event> getEvents() {
        return events;
    }
}
```

Now the type speaks by itself what relationship is returned and therefore application method that returns it guarantees that relation exists. But then each relationship would have its own class or interface;

EDIT:

**[C]**

Each relationship is represented using a generic class like `Tuple<Competition, List<Event>>` and `Competition` does not have the getter for list of events?

Comment: Option B seems like it could spiral out of control really fast. ComptetitoinVenue / CompetitionEvent / CompetitionEventVenue?

Comment: True. Also, CompetitionVenue and VenueCompetitions etc. See edited question with new option C

Answer (score 1):

I try to follow the "clean code" idea of never returning null (at least as much as I can).  That idea suggests that option B (two subclasses) is the better alternative.

I have an actual case that explains this... our system allows you to log a `Ticket` against various other entities in the system, but only against one type, so you might log it against a `Mill` or against a `Computer`.  In those cases we have a `MillTicket` and a `ComputerTicket`.  Only the `ComputerTicket` has a reference to a `Computer`.  On the SQL side, they're just nullable foreign keys.

An advantage is that a `ComputerTicket` can have all kinds of fields that are only applicable when I'm logging a `Ticket` against a `Computer`.

What this prevents is the ability to have a `Ticket` against 2 different entities, so that's a design decision with a pretty significant consequence.  Also, it means that it's relatively difficult to retroactively change a `ComputerTicket` into a `MillTicket` if someone changes their mind.  It can be done but it's a pain.

Comment: Is `Ticket` related to something else? How do you return Tickets and that other entities that you can join with?

Comment: I asked this as in your case `Ticket` and `ComputerTicket` are 'strong' types and they have their purpose for business logic; but what if you need to eg display Tickets with Authors.

Comment: @igor - `Ticket` has the `CreatedByUser` property, so you can get from a `User` to all the `Ticket`s they created.  You can also get from a `Computer` to all the `ComputerTickets` logged against it.

Answer (score 0):

Your model is clear example of abstraction, but your are approaching it from wrong way. You want to know location of competition, but you don't know what kind of location it is. So you should create an interface or abstract class that defines this location (lets call it `Location`) and then derive `Venue` and `Event` from it.

Also, you are first talking about domain model and then talking about SQL joins. You are mixing the two things together which is **never** a good thing. Focus either on one or the second, but never on both at the same time.

Comment: `Venue` and `Event` does not have anything in common, and there is no reason to be of the same (sub)type. Just because we sometimes need one or another that doesn't mean they should be of the same type - and we might need them bought in the same time. Next, sql join here means we have a single place where both objects come. That is a good thing to notice. Will update question.

Comment: @igor They do have something in common: They mean same thing to Competition. And it doesn't have to be subtype. It can be an interface. And where do they come from has absolutely no relevance to how they should be modeled.

Comment: They do **not** mean the same thing to Competition. It's simply 2 different entities related to Competition. From your last sentence - this means you vote for A? As that approach defines the relationships without knowing how they gonna be used.

Answer (score 0):

If you only ever need to use either Venue OR Event but never both at the same time, that's pretty much a sum type. I posted an answer a while back [showing how to encode them in C#](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/233185/116461). Unfortunately it's only really practical with lambdas, so unless you're using Java 8, the `match` method is going to be verbose as hell to use. You could, however, still make use of `instanceof` to distinguish between the options just as you're already doing in option B. The catch is that using `instanceof`, if you later add an extra alternative you'll have to find every place you made an `if ... else if ...` and add the new alternative into the code. Also, this only works for a finite number of possibilities, but that sounds like what you have here.

Using that as a foundation, you could create a class `Either<A, B>` that contains a value of either type A or type B, where A and B could be `Venue` and `Event`. E.g.

```
public class Competition {
    private Either<Venue, Event> venueOrEvent;
    ...
}
```

If instead what you need is a finite number of types of `Competition` (i.e. there's exactly 5 competition types, each with its own set of data) you could just do what you were already doing in option B, except making them inner classes of the `Competition` class and giving `Competition` a private constructor so no one can sneak in additional subclasses.

Comment: It's not OR (ive updated the question).