# Inheritance/OO design question

Tags: object-oriented

This will probably wind up being a fairly simple question, but it needs some background first... I'm modelling various hardware switches, which can be turned on and off. The switches are configurable, allowing a user to specify the numeric values that are sent to the hardware to signal that it should turn on or off. This is the `Switch` class:-

```
public class Switch
{
    public Id { get; set; }
    public SwitchConfig Config { get; set; }

    public void TurnOn()
    {
        WriteToSerialPort(Id, Config.OnValue);
    } 

    public void TurnOff()
    {
        WriteToSerialPort(Id, Config.OffValue);
    } 
}

public class SwitchConfig
{
    public int OnValue { get; set; }
    public int OffValue { get; set; }
}
```

So far so good.

I now need to model a new type of switch that can not only be turned on and off, but can also have a temperature threshold set, so it seems sensible to inherit from the `Switch` class. The configuration will also need extending to include min/max permitted temperatures, e.g.:-

```
public TemperatureSwitchConfig : SwitchConfig
{
    public int MinTemperature { get; set; }
    public int MaxTemperature { get; set; }
}
```

The specialised switch class will look something like this:-

```
public TemperatureSwitch : Switch
{
    public void SetTemperature(int temperature)
    {
        var temperatureSwitchConfig = Config as TemperatureSwitchConfig;

        if (temperature < temperatureSwitchConfig.MinTemperature
            || temperature > temperatureSwitchConfig.MaxTemperature)
        {
             return;
        }

        WriteToSerialPort(Id, temperature);
    }
}
```

It doesn't feel "right" where I'm having to cast the `Config` property. I'm sure there must be a slicker OO solution to this, but I think "analysis paralysis" has set in and I can't see the wood for the trees! Or am I worrying over nothing - is the casting an acceptable solution in this scenario?

Comment: Why do you need config? Why not just put the fields into the switch itself?

Comment: Why don't you simply inject the Config in your method? Your `SetTemperature` signature would look like this `SetTemperature(int temperature, TemperatureSwitchConfig config)`

Comment: @Euphoric see my comments on the answer from Geerten below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to remove `Config` property from the class and put all the properties of it into the class itself. Then, you set those properties in constructor of each switch or as properties.

You say that `SwitchConfig` comes from XML serialization. What if you want to parametrize that serialization in some way, this is usually done using attributes in model classes (`SwitchConfig` in your case). Then the `SwitchConfing` and transitively `Switch` becomes dependent on module for XML serialization.

What if you would want to create the switches based on something else than XML? Then you would need to needlessly create the `Config` classes, instead of setting the parameters in constructors or properties.

Last thing that comes to mind is: How do you create concrete type of `Switch` class? Eg. how do you decide to create `Switch` or `TemperatureSwitch`? Probably based on type of `SwitchConfig`. If you already have code like this, why not just make it into full-featured factory, that builds specific switches based on XML data? And the XML serialization can be encapsulated internally inside this factory.

And if you are worrying about having to change many things when configuration changes, then you can do what Karl Bielefeldt said and use weak-typed deserialization instead of explicit class model.

Answer (score 4):

Your comment about needing to generate the `Config` from xml adds a whole new dimension to the problem.  Strong types are most helpful at compile time, which isn't applicable here.  My inclination would be to instead create a `Dictionary` to hold the parsed config, and use it like:

```cs
public TemperatureSwitch : Switch
{
    public void SetTemperature(int temperature)
    {
        if (temperature < config["MinTemperature"]
         || temperature > config["MaxTemperature"])
        {
             return;
        }

        WriteToSerialPort(Id, temperature);
    }
}
```

You can put validation into your parser code, or into the setter code.  Alternately, you could just forego the `Config` altogether, and have your xml parser code create the `Switch` objects directly, with individual fields for the config items.

Comment: There's no reason you can't have static typing just because you're parsing XML at runtime.

Comment: Of course.  If you notice, I proposed that as an alternate.  It's just that most of the benefits of static typing happen at compile time.  If you have to do the checking at runtime anyway, you may as well take advantage of that if it simplifies your code.  Note that the dictionary has a static type.

Comment: The dictionary fails to distinguish between the different kinds of configs though. Now, given a dictionary, I don't know if it has 1) all the fields required of a regular switch's configs; 2) all the fields required of a temperature switch's configs; or 3) neither. In order to avoid #3, you'd have to check that #1 or #2 before you return the dictionary, and at that point you might as well return actual `Config` types.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the config a parameter:

```
public abstract class Switch<TConfig> where TConfig : SwitchConfig
{
    public Id { get; set; }
    public TConfig { get; set; }

    public void TurnOn()
    {
        WriteToSerialPort(Id, Config.OnValue);
    } 

    public void TurnOff()
    {
        WriteToSerialPort(Id, Config.OffValue);
    } 
}

public class NormalSwitch : Switch<SwitchConfig>
{
}

public TemperatureSwitch : Switch<TemperatureSwitchConfig>
{
    public void SetTemperature(int temperature)
    {

        if (temperature < Config.MinTemperature
            || temperature > Config.MaxTemperature)
        {
             return;
        }

        WriteToSerialPort(Id, temperature);
    }
}
```

Comment: Programmers is [about] conceptual questions and answers are [expected to _explain_ things](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer). Throwing code dumps instead of explanation is like copying code from IDE to whiteboard: it may look familiar and even sometimes be understandable, but it feels weird... just weird. [Whiteboard doesn't have compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5508110/839601)

Comment: The answer is "use a parameter". The code simply illustrates that.

Comment: I toyed with the idea of generics but it's likely there could be further levels of inheritance (e.g. something inheriting from `TemperatureSwitch`). While it's still possible, it does result in an explosion of <TConfig> parameters everywhere. Something to bear in mind though.

Answer (score 0):

Most OO languages properly implement the rules of subtyping, as stated by Barbara Liskov (in ["A behavioral notion of subtyping"](http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~neelam/courses/788/lwb.pdf), see fig. 4). In particular, if you have a method with the signature

```
X method(Y arg1, Z arg2);
```

then you can override this method in a subclass using the signature

```
A method(B arg1, C arg2);
```

where:

- A is a subclass of X (or is X)
- B is a superclass of Y (or is Y)
- C is a superclass of Z (or is Z)

In your case, your `TemperatureSwitch` class could override

```
SwitchConfig Switch::Config();
```

with

```
TemperatureSwitchConfig Switch::Config();
```

Thus, if you have a variable of type `TemperatureSwitch`, its `Config` method will return you a `TemperatureSwitchConfig`. If you have a variable of type `Switch` that actually points to a `TemperatureSwitch`, then its `Config method` will return you a `SwitchConfig`, which is actually a `TemperatureSwitchConfig` (just like your current situation).

Comment: Your explanation has nothing to do with LSP. Its just basic polymorphism of inheritance.

Comment: @Euphoric: of course it does. Quoting from wikipedia: "Liskov's principle imposes some standard requirements on signatures 1. Contravariance of method arguments in the subtype 2. Covariance of return types in the subtype 3. No new exceptions should be thrown by methods of the subtype, except where those exceptions are themselves subtypes of exceptions thrown by the methods of the supertype."

Comment: That is just effect of applying LSP. Not LSP itself. Quoting from wikipedia: "It states that, in a computer program, if S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T may be replaced with objects of type S (i.e., objects of type S may substitute objects of type T) without altering any of the desirable properties of that program"

Comment: My opinion is that the Liskov substitution principle encompasses more than you think it does. I really think the very definition of the Subtype Relation (the constraint rule) is an integral part of LSP. The rules about the covariance of return type and contravariance of argument types are stated in Liskov's original paper, "A behavioral notion of subtyping", see fig. 4. I give you the benefit of the doubt, though, by editing the first sentence of my answer to not refer to LSP directly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use the C# generics (or equivalent in your choice of language). so basically your 1st code block would look like:

```
    public class Switch<T> where T:SwhitchConfig
    {
       public Id { get; set; }
       public T Config { get; set; }

       public void TurnOn()
       {
           WriteToSerialPort(Id, Config.OnValue);
       } 

       public void TurnOff()
       {
            WriteToSerialPort(Id, Config.OffValue);
       } 
   }

   public class SwitchConfig
   {
       public int OnValue { get; set; }
       public int OffValue { get; set; }
   }
```

And your specialized implementation would look like:

```
    public TemperatureSwitch : Switch<TemperatureSwitchConfig>
    {

    }
```

Comment: Programmers is [about] conceptual questions and answers are [expected to _explain_ things](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer). Throwing code dumps instead of explanation is like copying code from IDE to whiteboard: it may look familiar and even sometimes be understandable, but it feels weird... just weird. [Whiteboard doesn't have compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5508110/839601)

Answer (score -1):

**Disclaimer**: My C# is pretty rusty. The syntax may be off.

> I now need to model a new type of switch that can not only be turned on and off, but can also have a temperature threshold set, so it seems sensible to inherit from the Switch class.

A natural response, but you should be careful. [Inheritance is dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21116956/1272233), it shouldn't be your first reaction to a problem.

Here's my take on this:

First, since all your fields are public, it doesn't make sense to make `TurnOn` and `TurnOff` methods. It'd be slightly better to have these be static functions. The upside is that when you need to change the implementation of `TurnOn`/`TurnOff` or provide alternate implementations, you don't need to recompile anything that depends on `Switch`.

Next, you can easily make `Switch` immutable, and you should prefer immutability when possible. By making it immutable you don't have to worry about keeping track of possible state changes as you pass `Switch` values around in your program. It also allows you to use them as keys in dictionaries, since a key's equality and hashcode shouldn't depend on mutable state.

With that out of the way, we need to tackle the issue that there's more than one kind of switch. You need to make a decision here: do I want to make introducing new types of switches easy, or make it easy to do new things with the switches you already have? Given that these are hardware switches, it'd guess that the addition of new switch types will be a relatively rare event. If that's the case, you'd benefit from using a [sum type](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/228125/116461). This will restrict us to a finite set of kinds of switches but give us a type-safe way to distinguish between them and ensure you appropriately handle each one. So, your code would go something like this (constructors omited for brevity):

```
// Switch.cs
public abstract Switch {
    private Switch() {} // Prevent inheritance outside of this scope

    public abstract R Match<R>(Func<NormalSwitch, R> IfNormal, Func<TemperatureSwitch, R> IfTemp);

    public sealed NormalSwitch : Switch {
        public <IdType> Id { get; }
        public SwitchConfig Config { get; }

        public R Match<R>(Func<NormalSwitch, R> IfNormal, Func<TemperatureSwitch, R> IfTemp); {
            return IfNormal(this);
        }
    }

    public sealed TemperatureSwitch : Switch {
        public <IdType> Id { get; }
        public TempSwitchConfig Config { get; }

        public R Match<R>(Func<NormalSwitch, R> IfNormal, Func<TemperatureSwitch, R> IfTemp); {
            return IfTemp(this);
        }
    }
}

// SwitchFunctions.cs
public static class SwitchFunctions {
    public static void TurnOn(NormalSwitch Switch) { ... }
    public static void TurnOff(NormalSwitch Switch) { ... }
}

// TempSwitchFunctions.cs
public static class TempSwitchFunctions {
    public static void TurnOn(TemperatureSwitch Switch) { ... }
    public static void TurnOff(TemperatureSwitch Switch) { ... }
    public static void SetTemperature(TemperatureSwitch Switch) { ... }
}
```

Now in your client code you may do this:

```
Switch switch = parseXml()
switch.match(
    IfNormal: NormalSwitch => TurnOn(NormalSwitch),
    IfTemperature: TempSwitch => {
        TurnOn(TempSwitch);
        SetTemperature(TempSwitch);
    }
);
```

It's all strongly-typed, and you can write alternative implementations to the switch functions without having to recompile anything that depends on the original implementations.

Uh oh, I introduced some functional programming into your code. But that's OK, since your `Switch` was just a data container.

Comment: Downvoter: Please explain your reasoning, in detail.

Comment: Your approach came to mind when I first started this application. Rather than strictly adhering to the rule that a class should contain both data and behaviour, I wanted another class to be responsible for turning switches on and off. This seemed a more natural fit for my scenario - there are various dependencies involved in controlling a switch (e.g. writing to a serial port), and passing these to a whole load of "model" classes didn't feel quite right. Unfortunately the OO purists where I work won out, so I'm stuck with putting the behaviour in the class.

Comment: @AndrewStephens That's unfortunate. You *could* still turn `Switch` into a sum type even if you leave `TurnOn`, `TurnOff`, and `SetTemperature` as methods and it'd solve your casting problem, but I don't know if the OO purists would like that. I'd bet you could get away with it if you used the Visitor pattern though; it's essentially the OO workaround when you don't have lambdas and delegates.