# What procedural languages support algebraic data types?

Tags: procedural, algebraic-data-type

One of the things I like about the new Apple language Swift is that it combines procedural programming with algebraic data types. What other languages do this?

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Comment: Technically, this is neither a list nor shopping question. It has a simple, objective, canonical answer: "Yes".

Comment: @JörgWMittag http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183183/165773

Comment: Edited to address Jorg's point. Yes or no wasn't the answer I was hoping for ;)

Comment: I'm not asking anyone to recommend anything.

Comment: @JohnDeHope the 'or favorite off site resource' in the close reason is intended to capture the "can you find this thing for me?".  Its covered in the 'Asking for link to things' section of the link that gnat initially provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ML family: OCaml, SML, F#**

ML was (AFAIK) the first language to directly support algebraic data types; ML and its descendants have always at least had mutable state through reference variables.

**Racket**

Within the Racket family there is `#lang plai` which directly provides algebraic types.

`#lang racket` supports the same style of program using multiple subtypes of a struct type and using the `match` macro. There's a good talk on the relationship between algebraic types and this design [in this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O9fnN6prNo8#t=1937), part of the Brown online PL course.

Typed Racket provides explicit union types and matching through the `match` macro.

**Scala**

Scala's case classes are algebraic types built on top of the JVM's class system.

**Others**

Wikipedia [has a list of languages with algebraic data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type#Programming_languages_with_algebraic_data_types); languages on this list with mutability include Nemerle and haXe.

I've conflated *match* style operations with algebraic datatypes here, partly because convenience is really all that separates some of these languages from assembly; you can define ad-hoc algebraic types in any language you like, it just won't be very nice.

Comment: Thanks, that wikipedia page was pretty much what I was looking for. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

You can [go full imperative](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/imperative-programming-1.html) in ML-family languages (e.g. Ocaml) while enjoying ADTs and pattern matching.

You can have a *sort of* ADT in Algol descendants like C and Pascal by using [variant records](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu19.html). But you will get very little syntactic sugar. You'll have to pack/unpack and check the variants manually, without the static type safety that e.g. Haskell would give you.

Comment: I would dare say that you can go full imperative in Haskell too, by using monads. Maybe some Haskell expert can comment on this.

Comment: @Giorgio [Some people consider Haskell the "world's finest imperative language."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622524/why-is-haskell-sometimes-referred-to-as-best-imperative-language)

Comment: @Doval: That's why I wanted to mention Haskell. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Java/C# don't support ADTs out of the box but [with some boilerplate and lambdas you can pull it off](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159804/how-do-you-encode-algebraic-data-types-in-a-c-or-java-like-language).

If I'm not mistaken that's also pretty much what Scala's [case classes](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/107) are, minus the boilerplate.

Comment: Yes, Scala case classes are used to model algebraic data types. +1