# Avoiding a large amount of overloads

Tags: c#, object-oriented-design

I'm currently writing a mailing interface for our enterprise application. Dependent on the send mode (regular email, bulk email, templates, mailmerge, ...) our `Send()` method requires a bunch of parameters.

Now we have got this `Send()` method that offers to take around 20 parameters, with nearly 10 overloads and default values.

Now of course you could use the C# 4.0 feature of named parameters like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753902/avoiding-overload-hell-with-c-sharp-4-0), but even that would be a mess when mostly 10 of 15 overloaded parameters have to be used.

Is there some better practice?

Comment: Yes, use Parameter Objects: http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/introduce-parameter-object

Comment: @KilianFoth Not only that, sounds like he needs some form union/algebraic data type too, because I can't imagine how you get ~10 equivalent methods with ~20 parameters without most of those parameters being some sort of configuration value that can come in certain specific combinations.

Comment: @Doval You're right, most of them *are* configuration values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like your `Send()` method is doing too much and asking for too much information.

What happens when it has to deal with a template or mail merge? Is it really *sending* something? I don't think so, and so `Send` is a badly chosen name. But it's not the choice of the name which is bad here, but, again, the fact that `Send()` does too much: it sends e-mails, stores templates or does a mail merge and stores the results in a database (I suppose).

When you split the method into several smaller ones, your `Send()` one becomes smaller:

```
public void Send() // Actually sends regular e-mails or bulk e-mails.
public void StoreTemplate()
public void DoMailMerge()
```

Let's get back to `Send()`. If it still has too many arguments, you are possibly giving it configuration information. Instead, this information should either be loaded from a configuration file or be passed through properties to the instance of the object containing `Send()`.

Instead of:

```
sender.Send(from, bulkTo, title, body, timeout, mailsPerSecond);
```

you should be doing:

```
sender.bulkMailsPerSecond = this.mailsPerSecond;
sender.Send(bulkTo, title, body);
```

given that:

- `from` is now in the configuration, loaded directly by `Sender` when needed,
- `timeout` becomes a property of `Sender` with a default value.

---

The next step is to reduce the size of `Sender`: you may end up noticing that the class is too large and doing too much. For example, you may end up exporting templating-related stuff in a separate class, or use inheritance in order to apply custom logic for regular e-mails and bulk e-mails:

```
public abstract class Sender
{
    protected Address From { get { ... } }
    protected TimeSpan Timeout { get { ... } set { ... } }
}

public class RegularEmailSender : Sender
{
    public void Send(Address to, string title, string body) { ... }
}

public class BulkEmailSender : Sender
{
    private int BulkMailsPerSecond { get { ... } set { ... } }
    public void Send(IEnumerable<Address> bulkTo, string title, string body) { ... }
}
```

Comment: RegularEmailSender and BulkEmailSender with inheritance is an idea I haven't yet thought of. I like it. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, using different `Senders` looks a little bit questionable to me. This might be ok if `Sender` is a lightweight object, but what, for example, if a sender needs to establish some network connection at the construction, or has some other kind of heavy initialization? Then this initialization would be multiplied by the number of different senders. If it is has too much responsibilities, a better strategy might be to make it a facade for some internal helper classes which work behind the scenes, instead of using inheritance.

Comment: @DocBrown: if a sender needs to establish some network connection, this business logic will go to the abstract `Sender` class and won't be duplicated. This being said, a facade is a valid solution too.

Comment: My comment was not about code duplication, it was about what happens when you have to create multiple sender objects instead of one. Imagine what happens when each sender needs to connect to a mail server or a database before you can use it, then your suggestion implies to create multiple connections where formerly only one was needed. This beeing said, when each "Sender" is only something like a lightweight proxy object to a shared connection, using inheritance might be a valid solution, too. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

From your comments it seems you have something like this:

```
Send(Data data, Address address, A a, B b, C c) { ... }

Send(Data data, Address address, A a, D d, E e, F f) { ... }

Send(Data data, Address address, B b, H h, J j) { ... }
```

Where `A`, `B`, `C`, ... are types of values used for configuration. You're implicitly working with a `Configuration` type that can come in a finite set of "shapes" or combinations. You want a [tagged union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union), but C# doesn't support them directly. However, [you can implement one with inheritance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159804/how-do-you-encode-algebraic-data-types-in-a-c-or-java-like-language). The key is to recognize that you can create an abstract class that has a *finite* set of subclasses by:

1. Giving the abstract class a private constructor.
2. Making the subclasses inner sealed classes of the abstract class.

The inner subclasses have access to the abstract class's private constructor, but top-level classes don't, so no one can add a new subclass "from the outside".

So you'd have something like this:

```
abstract class Configuration {
    private Configuration() {
        // Prevent outside subclassing
    }

    public sealed class Conf1 : Configuration {
         public A a { get; set; }
         public B b { get; set; }
         public C c { get; set; }

         // Constructor boilerplate
    }

    public sealed class Conf2 : Configuration {
         // Different fields
         // Constructor boilerplate
    }

    // ... more subclasses
}
```

(I don't work with C# regularly; hopefully I haven't made any serious syntax mistakes.)

Then all you need is a safe way to examine which kind of `Configuration` subclass you got. This is essentially the visitor pattern, but you can make it more concise with delegates:

```
abstract class Configuration {
    ...
    public abstract R Match<R>(Func<Conf1, R> ifConf1, Func<Conf2, R> ifConf2, ...);
    ...
    public sealed class Conf1 : Configuration {
        ...
        public override R Match<R>(...) {
            // Each subclass calls the delegate corresponding to it
            return ifConf1(this);
        }
        ...
    }

    // And so on with every other subclass
 }
```

Now you can reduce your `Send` to:

```
Send(Data data, Address address, Configuration config) {
    return config.Match(
        ifConf1: conf1 => { ... },
        ifConf2: conf2 => { ... },
        ...
    );
}
```

This all assumes that the number of combinations of configuration values is limited and doesn't change terribly often. I've assumed that, for example, all the `Send` methods use the same underlying mechanism and that it can simply be configured in a variety of ways. If you wanted to abstract over different kinds of sending services (e.g. e-mail vs some sort of IPC vs SOAP) then I'd use an `interface` similar to [MainMa's](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/271630/116461) `Sender` class since that solution always allows you to add new kinds of "senders" easily.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are doing too much in the send method, where ideally it should be only used to send email but not to do processing like mail merge, However without seeing your method signatures I can't say that for sure.

Using a lot of overloads with default values will often cause a lot of confusion especially if it's not done proper manner.

One way to avoid this is to use a DTO object to pass into the method instead of using overloads. You can create a single method and use a DTO to pass in values to the method.